# Swift: open "in menu" option

Tags: ios, menu, swift

I'd like to get the "Open In" menu to let my app open a file with another one selectable by the user.
This is my code, but I can't get it to work

```
var url: NSURL! = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: "pbz")
        self.controller = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL:     NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: "pbz")!)
        let v = sender as UIView
        let ok = self.controller.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(v.bounds, inView: self.view, animated: true)
```

Do you have any idea about that? It compiles but gives me an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error at runtime, at the second instruction.
Similiar code worked for me with Objective-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filename`.pbz probably doesn't exist in your main bundle for some reason. With your current code, that will be a fatal error and cause your application to crash.

You're implicitly unwrapping `url` on your first line by declaring `url` as `NSURL!`. You're force unwrapping your `NSURL` in on your second line by appending `!` to your call to `URLForResource`. If `filename`.pbz isn't found in your main bundle, then your application is going to crash on your second line, or if you try to use `url` somewhere when it's `nil`.

**You should only use force unwrapping if you are *absolutely* sure that variable will *never* be `nil`, and only use implicit unwrapping if you are absolutely sure that variable will not be `nil` when you use it.**

What you should do instead is check to make sure that the `url` you get back from `URLForResource` is not `nil` before you try to use it. You can use [Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_490) to do that easily and *safely*:

```
if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: "pbz") {
    self.controller = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: url)
    let v = sender as UIView
    let ok = self.controller.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(v.bounds, inView: self.view, animated: true)
} else {
    /* resource doesn't exist */
}
```